# Python: Binary number conversion with an extra letter

Tags: python, binary, numbers

I am converting large binary numbers to decimal form in a python project.
I was using this method to convert binary numbers:

```
for number in binary_numbers:
   integer = int(number, 2)
   integers.append(integer)
```

This accesses a list of binary_numbers and adds the converted number to another list of integers.

Given this binary number: '1101100111001001110110001100100111011001110010001101100011001001110110011100100111011000110010001101100111001000110110001100100'

I got this:
144745261873314177475604083946266324068L

The number is correct, but there is an 'L' added to the end.

The next smallest number in my series was:
'110110011100100111011000110010011101100111001000110110001100100'
which gave me a decimal value of 7846656369001524324 (no 'L')

Why is the 'L' there? Where did it come from? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: L stands for long :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me. I didn't see anything before, but now i found it and it makes sense.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when does python start considering numbers large?